# Access elements on UIWindow XCode UITesting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have a banner kind `UIView`, which appears and disappear after certain amount of time on tap of a button action. This is being presented on a `UIWindow` level. I want to access this banner `UIView` and `UILabel` inside the view, for automating the testcase in XCode UITesting. How to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter where the banner exists in the app's view hierarchy. UI Testing just uses accessibility to find elements. As long as there is a valid `accessibilityIdentifier` set on the banner you can find it via a simple query.

Since there is a `UILabel` inside try finding the banner via that. This checks if the label is in he view hierarchy.

```
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Banner Text"].exists)
```

If the view isn't removed but just set to hidden, you will want to use `hittable` over `exists`. This will make sure that the element is not only visible, but also not `hidden`.

```
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Banner Text"].hittable)
```

Comment: It's always better to refer to elements by their accessibilityIdentifier rather than their text: that way your tests won't break when you localize your app and you test you app on a device or simulator running in a different locale.

Comment: Accepted @DavidPhillipOster. 
I have a question here. if I execute user id field on signon screen like following, 

`XCUIApplication().scrollViews.otherElements.textFields["USERID"].accessibilityIdentifier` 

it is returning false. This means `accessibilityIdentifier` is not set. But still testcase succeeds. 

Now the question is, how can access if the `UILabel`'s `accessibilityIdentifier`  is not set ? Any idea ?

Comment: The `XCUIApplication()...........textFields["USERID"]` query will find an element in your applications UI which is a textfield with either current content "USERID" or accessibilityLabel = USERID. Checkout the `XCUIElementAttributes` protocol to find the various properties available.